# Recognize Logos and their Sources

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

I am working on a problem where I have to recognize logos and also output about the logo placement (logo source). I have attached an image below for visuals, if any of the logos on the below image is detected, we have to output its source as well. The logos detected on the back wall of Jürgen Klopp source should be Wall of Logos and the Nike logo on Jürgen Klopp shirt source should be shirt/apparel.

I hope that makes the problem clear. For basic logo detection, what I have in mind is to try SOTA detectors i.e. yolov5/yolov8/yolonas but for the source what do you think could be a better solution? I can add the logo sources as a separate class to the detector model as well but If you can suggest any other way, it would be appreciated.

[image]